# Fixed scrollable sidebar goes over the page title/header

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I am designing a page in which I have fixed sidebar of height 100% and a right side main content. But problem with that is it goes over the title/banner when I keep `top: 0;`.

If I keep `top: 1;` sidebar comes down but it creates a empty space between sidebar and title when I scroll the page like this shown in image[image]

I want my sidebar to take whole screen tat is 100% height and at at the same time it should not go over the banner.

My code is

```css
#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 1;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">

</div>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>

</div>

<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>

</div>
```

If there is any trick to achieve that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to make the sidebar the height of the screen minus a specific amount of pixels, and then align it to the bottom.

```
.sidenav {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  top: auto;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
```

Also `top: 1` is not valid css, it requires a unit like px, em etc.

Comment: the problem still remains if I scroll the page a gap is created between banner and sidebar equal to the amount of subtracted pixel in this case is 50px. look I have uploaded the portion where gap comes, in the question itself.

Comment: @Deb check my answer I handled it

Comment: Can the header also be fixed? You may need to use javascript to get this working otherwise.

Comment: yeah that's true or make sidebar `sticky`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`margin-top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/margin) to leave specific space from the top and because you sidebar is fixed when you your page turn into scroll one will look unresponsive and if you don't want to change the `position` of `div#sidenav` you can handle it by setting the position of the `div#banner` to [`sticky`](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/)

### The following is an example

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#banner {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.sidenav {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 160px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
</div>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
</div>
```

Or you can simply make the `div#sidenav` `sticky` instead of making it `fixed`

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#banner {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: skyblue;
}

.sidenav {
  height: 100vh; /*height: 100%; here don't work but in browser do*/
  width: 160px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.sidenav a {
  padding: 6px 8px 6px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.main {
  margin-left: 160px;
  /* Same as the width of the sidenav */
  font-size: 28px;
  /* Increased text to enable scrolling */
  padding: 0px 10px;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="banner">
</div>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <h2>Sidebar</h2>
  <p>This sidebar is of full height (100%) and always shown.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: on scrolling the page a gap is created between sidebar and banner/title.

Comment: But banner/header has become fixed here. It always shows on te top it doesnt scroll.

Comment: @Deb if you're setting `fixed` sidebar and don't want the `sticky` or `fixed` header the problem will always be there but I have another solution. To make the sidebar `sticky`  check I made an edit

Comment: thanks for help but problem still not solved. one problem remains, hope you can sort that out too, in the updated part the main content that is the right part starts only after the fixed sidebar. taht is the left part and right part dont start at the same place may be because of fixed property of sidebar.

Comment: the circulation of turning position to `fixed` and `sticky` will affect the other contents so that you can align them manually till you satisfied